# Differential Equation for practical problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem at hand, which I want to model with a differential equation:

A person is consuming a constant amount of alcohol m per day.
The alcohol in the person's blood is being decomposed with a constant rate k.

Now I would like to model a differential equation for the amount of Alcohol in the person blood - A(t), and also a solution with the property A'(t) = 0.

Any advice/hints welcome.

Comment: Assume that the drinking is done *continuously*. It is not entirely clear what constant rate $k$ means. Probably it is meant that when there is $A$ in the blood, the rate of change due to decay is $kA$. Then the model is $A'(t)=m-kA(t)$.

Comment: Isn't it "m*t"?

Comment: It isn't $mt$. The **rate** of ingestion is $m$.

Comment: Not sure I understand. m is the *amount* drunk daily by her - do we mean the same?

Comment: Yes, it means here that the **rate** of consumption is $m$ **per day.**

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the drinking is done *continuously*, day and night, night and day.

It is not entirely clear what constant rate $k$ means. Probably what  is meant is that when there is an amount $A$ in the blood, the rate of change due to decay (metabolization) is $kA$. We assume the units are chosen so they are compatible with those of $m$, say ml per day.  Then the model is 
$$A'(t)=m-kA(t)$$
(rate in minus rate out).

There are many ways to solve this DE. One simple way is to let $y=m-kA(t)$. Then $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-k\frac{dA}{dt}=-ky.$$
The differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=-ky$ is the familiar DE of exponential decay. Its general solution is $y=Ce^{-kt}$. Now one can write down the general formula for $A(t)$.

The solution that has $A'(t)=0$ can be written down without solving the DE. If our friend starts off pretty high, with $A(0)=\frac{m}{k}$, then her blood alcohol level remains constant, with ingestion matching decay.

Comment: ah..so for this case we have C = m/k, right? thanks!